# Why am I get a Key Error

Tags: python

import math

```
def Richter_Joules( scale ):
sum=(1.5*scale)+4.8
return 10**sum


def Richter_TNT( R_scale ):
val=Richter_Joules(R_scale)/(4.184*10**9)    # One ton TNT yields 4.184x109 #joules
return val

L=[1.0,  5.0,  9.0,  9.1,  9.5]


def main( ):

print( "Richter       Joules                      TNT" )
print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[0],  Richter_Joules( L[0] ),  Richter_TNT( L[0] ) ))
print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[1],  Richter_Joules( L[1] ),  Richter_TNT( L[1] ) ))
print("{ }    { }      { }".format( L[2],  Richter_Joules( L[2] ),    Richter_TNT( L[2] ) ))
print("{ }    { }      { }".format( L[3],  Richter_Joules( L[3] ),    Richter_TNT( L[3] ) ))
print("{ }    { }     { }".format( L[4],   Richter_Joules( L[4] ),    Richter_TNT( L[4] ) ))

print("\n")

r=float( input( "Please enter a Richter Scale Value : " ) )

print( "Richter Scale Value: ", r)
RJ = Richter_Joules(r)
RT = Richter_TNT(r)
print( "Equivalence in joule:", RJ)
print( "Equivalence in tons of TNT: ", RT)  

main()
```

The Program Gives an Option to enter a Richter scale value but then when you enter a value it gives this

I have looked up what a key error was and I could not figure out what I have done wrong with my stuff. Any help is appreciated

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\19ktw01\appdata\local\temp\tmpor5fg1.py in <module>()
     32 print( "Equivalence in tons of TNT: ", RT)
     33 
---> 34 main()

c:\users\19ktw01\appdata\local\temp\tmpor5fg1.py in main()
     16 
     17  print( "Richter       Joules                      TNT" )
---> 18  print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[0],  Richter_Joules( L[0] ),  Richter_TNT( L[0] ) ))
     19  print("{ }    { }         { }".format( L[1],  Richter_Joules( L[1] ),  Richter_TNT( L[1] ) ))
     20  print("{ }    { }      { }".format( L[2],  Richter_Joules( L[2] ),    Richter_TNT( L[2] ) ))

KeyError: ' '
```

What have I done Wrong

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Please edit your question to make sure you have the correct indentation for your code, this is very important and will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces between the braces, i.e.

```
print("{}    {}         {}".format( L[0],  Richter_Joules( L[0] ),  Richter_TNT( L[0] ) ))
```